# Openresty torch module loading issue

Tags: nginx, lua, luajit, torch, openresty

I'm trying to use openresty with torch for a Rest api for a neural network. 
First query works,  any query after that fails.

## Nginx Config

```
workers processes 1;

error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    workers connections 1024
}
http {
    server {
        listen 5050;
        location /{
            default type text/html;
            content_by_lua_file /home/yiftach/testFile.lua;
        } 
    } 
}
```

## testFile.lua

```
require "nn" 
local tensorA=torch.zeros(1,1)
ngx.say(tensorA:size()[1])
```

### The error:

```
Lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /home/yiftach/testFile.lua: attempt to index global 'torch' (a nil value)
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: require 'torch'? I don't see any usage of nn package

Comment: there is no 'torch' package, nn includes the torch object

Answer (score 1):

You didn't `require` the torch library.
Add `local torch = require "torch"` at the top.